# MySQL Reverse Engineer only tables that have data

Tags: mysql

I would like to reverse engineer a database, while ignoring the empty tables.

Currently I have to manually search and click for about 200 tables from the checkbox GUI.

What I have tried so far: I saw a script option using mysqlclient in python but unfortunately can't get that to install. I also saw an command to to drop all the empty tables but that command doesn't work with cascade, and it would need to be a cascade drop.

What I want: Is there some way I can still see the relationships without the manual reading and clicking?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `TABLES` table in `information_schema` database

Comment: What checkbox GUI.- in what ide?

Answer (score -1):

You can run:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[database name]'
    AND TABLE_ROWS > 0;
```